# No Touch ID / Face ID prompt in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, keychain

I am using the [KeychainAccess](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess) keychain wrapper for Swift to save and read to the keychain using biometrics.

When running in the simulator (Xcode 10.1, iOS 12.1) the Touch ID / Face ID prompt/dialogue is not shown. The value is written to and read from keychain without the user being asked to confirm with biometrics. When I run on a device the prompt comes as expected.

It would seem that the simulator is always in a state where the biometrics is already approved, even though I had not activated the matching touch/face.

Is this a bug or (or perhaps a feature) in the simulator or the SDK? I have an older Objective-C project that uses Apple's old KeychainWrapper, and there I get the prompt in the same simulator.

Comment: The simulator is not a complete replace for the actual device.  It's part of the use-case of the simulator.  Finally testing should always done on device before releasing RELEASE build

Answer (score -3):

You can use the following option to trigger Enrolled, Matching Touch/Face and Non-Matching Touch/Face

```
Simulator >> Hardware > Touch ID
Simulator >> Hardware > Face ID
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, as I said in my question the issue is not that I am not able to give it a matching/non matching biometric, but rather that I am never asked to do it.

Comment: Downvoting as this doesn't answer the original question.